# Should I use "not" or "don't"?

Tags: negation, do-support

Let's **not** make a big deal out of it.
 
Let's **don't** make a big deal out of it.

You are just trying to make us **not** practice.
You are just trying to make us **don't** practice.

Should I use "not" or "don't"?

Answer (score 8):

In your first pair

- *Let's not* is grammatically "correct" and common in all registers; using it in conversation will not make you sound affected or pedantic.
- *Let's don't* is grammatically "incorrect" but often heard informally; it should not be used in formal writing, but will not expose you to scorn if used in conversation.

In your second pair

- *Make us not practice* is grammatically acceptable, but would be used only in conversation; and even there something like *keep us from practicing* would be more usual.
- *Make us don't practice* is **un**acceptable in any register.

Comment: +1 except I don't think it's quite right to say ***Let's not** is grammatically "correct" and common in **all** registers*. Let's not kid ourselves that it would be considered okay in formal written contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers When I was very young there were still some academics who would demand "let us", but today? - I would be surprised to encounter an objection in LitCrit or history. Perhaps this is not the case in stuffier disciplines.

Comment: Sure, *let's* occurs more and more often in "academic" texts - but I think it's probably fair to say those would be from the "chatty/informal/populist" end of the spectrum, rather than what I understand by "formal written contexts".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, we're all populists now. [See](http://books.google.com/books?id=R3TfxY6BPngC&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=%22let's+turn+now+to%22+Shakespeare&source=bl&ots=b4DcSPRLnr&sig=vUL8si8jyHuc39V6rKj5bhCY5Y8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9oGJUaPdBoay8QSGlYDQBQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Let's&f=false) *Shakespeare's Humanism*, Cambridge, 2005, Robin Headlam Wells, Professor of English Literature and Director of the Centre for Research in Renaissance Studies at Roehampton. Many chapters originally appeared in very prestigious journals; you don't get much more formal than *MLR* and *Shakespeare Survey*.

Answer (score 3):

When working with 'let's' and 'don't' writing them out in full and saying them out loud could  help. For example:

"Let's don't make a big deal out of it" - this is, in full, "Let us do not make a big deal out of it" which is wrong.

and the other one:

"You are just trying to make us don't practice." - in full it is "You are just trying to make us do not practice"

Both those are obviously wrong.

Try this out loud and you will see it is correct: "Let's not make a big deal out of it."

Whilst I agree mostly with the first answer, in en-GB we would never use 'let's don't' informally/colloquially or ever.

I hope this gives you a way of identifying the correct way but no doubt there will be a devious exception somewhere!

Comment: I see no reason to suppose that [let's don't go](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22let%27s+don%27t+go%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example, is any less likely in the UK than the US.

Comment: Honestly, I have always thought of the "Let's don't" construct as a bit of a Briticism. I've never heard it used in casual conversation here in the US. But of course, it's a big place and I haven't been everywhere, so I could very well be mistaken.